# jQuery: Show hidden section and navigate to anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, href

I created a page with a bunch of `section` elements keyed to specific `id`s. The page also has a list of links pointing to each `section`, like so:

```
<li><a class='subsection-nav gotoStep1' href='#step-1'>Step 1 Title</a></li>
```

I'm using jQuery to show only one `section` at a time:

```
// Defaults
$('.document-subsection').hide();
$('.gotoStep1').addClass("active");
$('#step-1').show();
// Step 1
$('.gotoStep1').click(function() {
    $('.subsection-nav').removeClass('active');
    $('.gotoStep1').addClass("active");
    $('.document-subsection').hide();
    $('#step-1').show();
    return false;
});
// Etc.
```

The trouble is, the jQuery function seems to override the standard browser behavior of scrolling to the named `id`. I want clicking the link to both **show** the hidden section and **navigate** to the specified `id`. I can't imagine this would be very hard, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the

```
return false;
```

in your onclick callback. This will allow the browser to perform the default function of navigating the page to the element with the matched id.

Answer (score 1):

try `$(this).addClass("active");` instead of `$('.gotoStep1').addClass("active");`
This means only the link which you clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [plugin](http://djpate.com/2011/01/01/animated-scrollto-effect-jquery-plugin/) or [this](http://pagesofinterest.net/blog/2008/09/scroll-to-anchors-with-jquery/) way.